# Translate ctypes args from c++ to python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, args

I try to use ctypes for using DLL on python program.

This is C# code and function's args that I want to use in python:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int function(
  byte[] filename,
  byte[] name,
  IntPtr result,
  out IntPtr UnmanagedStringArray,
  out int iStringsCountReceiver);
```

The code below is my python code. I searched several sites but I could not find hint about argtypes.
Please help me use DLL in python.

```
mydll = c.cdll.LoadLibrary("test.dll")
func = mydll['function']
func.argtypes=( ....)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`byte[]` is equivalent to `char*` in C, so `c_char_p` will work.  `IntPtr` in C# is an integer the size of a pointer.  `c_void_p` should work.  `out` parameters require pointers.

You can try:

```
import ctypes as c
mydll = c.CDLL('./test')
func = mydll.function
func.argtypes = c.c_char_p,c_c_char_p,c.c_void_p,c.POINTER(c_void_p),c.POINTER(c.c_int)
func.restype = c.c_int
```